# Mirage/Pretender causes errors in Vitest

Tags: vite, vitest, miragejs, pretender.js

I'm working on migrating from Jest to Vitest (alongside CRA > Vite migration), and I think I've got everything working, except that using Mirage causes errors. Setting the vite config test environment between `happy-dom` and 'jsdom' both give different errors, though they appear to be related or similar or the same (just with `happy-dom` giving much more useful information!

My very simplified test:

```js
import { describe, expect, it } from "vitest"
import { createServer } from "miragejs";

describe('tests', () => {
  createServer({})
  it('works', () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

#### happydom error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
 ❯ interceptor node_modules/pretender/dist/pretender.js:1540:46
 ❯ new Pretender node_modules/pretender/dist/pretender.js:1638:32
 ❯ PretenderConfig._create node_modules/miragejs/dist/mirage-cjs.js:6398:14
 ❯ PretenderConfig.create node_modules/miragejs/dist/mirage-cjs.js:6259:27
 ❯ Server.config node_modules/miragejs/dist/mirage-cjs.js:6824:24
 ❯ new Server node_modules/miragejs/dist/mirage-cjs.js:6760:10
 ❯ Proxy.createServer node_modules/miragejs/dist/mirage-cjs.js:6725:10
 ❯ src/test.test.tsx:5:2
      3| 
      4| describe('tests', () => {
      5|   createServer({})
       |  ^
      6|   it('works', () => {
      7|     expect(true).toEqual(true)
```

#### jsdom error

```
Error: Errors occurred while running tests. For more information, see serialized error.
 ❯ Object.runTests node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-vite-node-externalize.6956d2d9.mjs:7048:17
 ❯ processTicksAndRejections node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
 ❯ async file:/Users/jtuzman-superdraft/dev/superdraft-core-admin/NEW-vite-admin/node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-vite-node-externalize.6956d2d9.mjs:10545:9
 ❯ Vitest.runFiles node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-vite-node-externalize.6956d2d9.mjs:10558:12
 ❯ Vitest.start node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-vite-node-externalize.6956d2d9.mjs:10479:5
 ❯ startVitest node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-vite-node-externalize.6956d2d9.mjs:11204:5
 ❯ start node_modules/vitest/dist/cli.mjs:666:9
 ❯ CAC.run node_modules/vitest/dist/cli.mjs:662:3

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Serialized Error: {
  "errors": [
    [Error: Internal error: Error constructor is not present on the given global object.],
  ],
}
```

#### `vite.config.ts`

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros"
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom", // or "happy-dom"
  },
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  esbuild: {
    logOverride: { 'this-is-undefined-in-esm': 'silent' }
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgrPlugin({
      svgrOptions: {
        icon: true,
      },
    }),
    macrosPlugin(),
    checker({
      typescript: true,
      overlay: {
        panelStyle: 'height: 100vh; max-height: unset;'
      }
    })
  ],
});
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/666) appears to deal with the same question but doesn't appear to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same thing. It's the `global: {}` statement. When I commented it out in my vite.config.ts file, my tests ran successfully. I haven't figured out another way to solve the global error yet that caused me to set that in the first place though.

Comment: Thank you, I see the same behaviour. Have you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

happy-dom does not provide an implementation for *XMLHttpRequest*, which is used by pretenderjs. The most straightforward walk around is to put the following line at the very top of your test code, before the the vitest environment:

```js
this.XMLHttpRequest = vi.fn()

//@vitest-environment happy-dom
```